# C# Browser Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am creating a Kiosk Application for opening a single URL everytime the app run.

But unable to create a frame in c# to open such URL.

Please suggest me hot to do this coding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the built in WebBrowser control?

Comment: If you use the WebBrowser control that David suggested, you can then just `.Navigate(yourUrl)` to where you want it to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From VS add a WebBrowser component to your 'Kiosk' application..

And when the form loads, simply do this..

```
    private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

        Uri url = new Uri("http://google.com");
        webBrowser1.navigate(url);

   }
```